# What do you call a person who uses a shield?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who is using a shield? In the same manner as "swordsman" or "axeman", not as in "shielded".

I've found

> Shieldbearer

but that's more of a title for someone carrying someone else's shield.

> Shield User

is something else I've found, but it sounds generic as anything.

Comment: What problem does this solve? Are you looking for a synonym for *brandish* or a specific usage of a shield as a battle tactic?

Comment: My particular problem is "How do you refer to someone's skill with a shield", "You're an excellent swordsman", "You're an excellent shield-something"

Comment: "You have excellent shield skills"?

Comment: The way I see it, a warrior uses a shield to defend him/herself *while* wielding a weapon offensively, so it's the less glamorous but more vital of the warrior's arsenal of skills - probably why it doesn't have its own skill title.  If someone has excellent shield skills, how about just calling them *"alive"*? ;-)

Comment: But what does one do with a shield that's a skill? Block? Attack? Ranged attack boomerang throwing shield? What's the skill? Hey.. you can hold that shield on your arm for hours! What a feat! A shield bearer? A good user of shield to do shield stuff? A blocker? Or an appellation of someone who carries a specific type of shield? But that's not a skill, that's just a shield-bearer title. [but if you insist that shield-bearing isn't a skill](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22shield+bearing%22+class%20skill)

Answer (score 2):

There is a word "shieldman" (or "shieldmaiden") that might apply here, but more generally one would be a warrior, knight, soldier, man-at-arms, etc. In times when this was relevant, skill with a shield would only prolong your life so long if you could not also wield a sword or other weapon.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wiktionary, ***shieldsman*** is a word. (*shieldman* is mentioned as a synonym also.)

> someone who carries a shield

There is a contemporary usage but low. (See: [Ngram result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shieldsman&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshieldsman%3B%2Cc0)). Some usages in Google Books suggest that it connotes shield mastery.

Also, I see the usage of *shield master* especially in video games.

The reason there is not a well-established term like swordsman might be that the use of shield is mastered along with a weapon. You focus on mastering the weapon rather than using the shield.